# How can i open Ionic Cordova application from http/https link

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to open cordova app from url with http/https protocols

When i hit https://open.myapp/com/test/123 to force me to open my app and handle the params '/test/123'.

I want to be http/https so in future this can be sharable on socials networks
Most ot answers are for specific platforms only or using custom schemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are called "deep links". There are several plugins for Cordova that support this, e.g.:

- https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking
- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks
- https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin
- https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

You will have to select he one that fits your requirements best, install and configure it.